# PHP SESSIONS Check if user is still in database, while logged in

Tags: php, mysql, session

Let's say the User named **Michael** is **registered**, and is in our database in table named **users**.

Michael browses my site, and while he does so, I delete his user from the table.
My login system works with sessions.

After user Michael was deleted from the database, the browser can browse the website with "Michael" until the session ends.

That's because after the session processes, it doesn't change unless you check every time.

My solution that may increase a huge engine load because of too many queries / requests:

In session.inc.php add a checker:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    $check = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = :user")
    $check->execute(array( ":user" => $_SESSION['user']));

    if (!$check->rowCount())
    {
        session_destroy();
    }
}
```

***It will check if theres a row with the exact same username he is logged in currently with the session, if not, it will destroy the session.***

**Question:**

Will that solution cause a large engine load, if my website gets many browsing users?

Is there a better method of doing this?

Comment: user name should be unique hence no need for the limit clause.

Comment: For this check, `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE user_name = :user` should be enough. Faster than fetching all data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you delete a row from "users" table just delete or expire the session of that user.

Comment: So when I delete a user from an admin panel, I can simply do Destory_session($username); ?

Answer (score 0):

Ayush - How are you going to destroy someone else's session?

user1761494 - The best method is to save sessions in database, this not only adds security to your website, also gives you full control over sessions. when you kick a user out (delete/ban) just delete the session record for that user along with it.

Comment: earlier i had assumed that there was a field in database for session and whenever he deletes session firstly, he sets that filed inactive then deletes it....